# Hide a Column in Telerik RadGrid hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have an hierarchy in Telerik RadGrid in ASP .Net as shown in below Fig. Data binding is at run time and dynamic.

My requirement is, I need to hide some columns programmatically like, **"OrderID"** in second level, **"EmployeeID"** in third level and **"OrderID"** in 4th level, but I need the those values for manipulation.
Could you help me to achieve this ..?
 [image]

Comment: You need those values on the client or server?  You can hide a column, but still have access to it on the server.  But if you are talking on the client, then that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code.

.aspx

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
   </telerik:RadGrid>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [ContactName] FROM [Contacts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [OrderID], [OrderDate] FROM [Orders] WHERE ([CustomerID] = @CustomerID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testDatabaseConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [UnitPrice], [Quantity], [OrderID] FROM [ProductInfo] WHERE ([OrderID] = @OrderID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Init(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DefineGridStructure();
}

private void DefineGridStructure()
{


    RadGrid1.ID = "RadGrid1";
    RadGrid1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    RadGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "CustomerID" };

    RadGrid1.Width = Unit.Percentage(98);
    RadGrid1.PageSize = 3;
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
    RadGrid1.AllowSorting = true;
    RadGrid1.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
    RadGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    RadGrid1.ShowStatusBar = true;

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageSize = 3;

    //Add columns
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn;
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "CustomerID";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "CustomerID";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "ContactName";
    boundColumn.UniqueName = "ContactName";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Contact Name";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);


    //Detail table - Orders (II in hierarchy level)
    GridTableView tableViewOrders = new GridTableView(RadGrid1);
    tableViewOrders.Name = "Child1";
    tableViewOrders.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
    tableViewOrders.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    tableViewOrders.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "OrderID" };

    GridRelationFields relationFields = new GridRelationFields();
    relationFields.MasterKeyField = "CustomerID";
    relationFields.DetailKeyField = "CustomerID";
    tableViewOrders.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields);

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders);

    //Add columns
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "OrderID";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "OrderID";
    tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "OrderDate";
    boundColumn.UniqueName = "OrderDate";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Date Ordered";
    tableViewOrders.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    //Detail table Order-Details (III in hierarchy level)
    GridTableView tableViewOrderDetails = new GridTableView(RadGrid1);
    tableViewOrderDetails.Name = "Child2";
    tableViewOrderDetails.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3";
    tableViewOrderDetails.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    tableViewOrderDetails.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "OrderID" };

    GridRelationFields relationFields2 = new GridRelationFields();
    relationFields2.MasterKeyField = "OrderID";
    relationFields2.DetailKeyField = "OrderID";
    tableViewOrderDetails.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields2);

    tableViewOrders.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrderDetails);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "UnitPrice";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Unit Price";
    tableViewOrderDetails.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Quantity";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    boundColumn.UniqueName = "Quantity";
    tableViewOrderDetails.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    //Add the RadGrid instance to the controls
    RadGrid1.PreRender += new EventHandler(RadGrid1_PreRender);
    RadGrid1.DetailTableDataBind += new GridDetailTableDataBindEventHandler(RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind);
}

void RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DetailTableView.Name == "Child1")
    {
        foreach (GridColumn column in e.DetailTableView.Columns)
        {
            if (column.UniqueName == "OrderDate")
            {
                column.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.DetailTableView.Name == "Child2")
    {
        foreach (GridColumn column in e.DetailTableView.Columns)
        {
            if (column.UniqueName == "Quantity")
            {
                column.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

.................

Please check the "RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind" event in above code.

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
GridBoundColumn a = new BoundColumn();
            a.Display = false;
```

or

```
            a.Visible = false;
```

Use Display in case you want to access that field otherwise use visible property

Comment: Worth pointing out that setting `Visible` property to `false` is actually removing particular column from `GridColumnCollection` (the column is not being counted while accessing `Count` property) and `Display` property set to `false` is preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Charan if you are needing certain values from columns for calculations you should try using the DataKeyNames and and ClientDataKeyNames properties of the RadGrid, rather than binding the values to a column then hiding the column. They can be set in the RadGrid as well as the MasterTableView.

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id, orderId" ClientDataKeyNames="id, myId, type">
```

You can access the values client and server side:

(JS):

```
function RowSelected(sender,eventArgs)
{
var MasterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
var row = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical()];
var myId = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("myId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to hide the column. Try to access cell property and attach css to that cell. In the css you can make content display:none

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Not-RocketScience: In design I'm using only <telerik:RadGrid></telerik:RadGrid>. It doesn't contain any columns here. All the columns and Rows are creating at run time. So we should achieve it at run time itself using C# coding. If possible by css can you explain that..?